# Succeed in OR to +?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

1. The king succeeds in the throne
2. The king succeeds in claiming the throne
3. The king succeeds to the throne
4. The king succeeds to claim the throne

**Which are acceptable? & what are the difference between them?**

`Thank you`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Succeed in OR to + noun/gerund/infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471662/succeed-in-or-to-noun-gerund-infinitive)

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  You have asked three nearly identical questions in the last day and a half, if not identical in wording, at least in concept.  It would be better to condense them into a single generalized question, instead of focusing on the specifics of succeed/fail or any other single word, try asking about verb + preposition + gerund in general (although you can use yours as examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*succeed* has two primary meanings, and your sentences contain examples of both of them. From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/succeed):

> 1 Achieve the desired aim or result.

When used in the active form, this is often followed by "in" followed by a verb phrase, as in sentence #2.

> 2.1 Become the new rightful holder of an office, title, or property.

This is the sense in your sentence #3.

Sentence #1 is grammatically correct, but when "succeed in" is followed by a noun phrase, it's usually an endeavor of some kind that you can be successful in, e.g. "succeeds in the game". A throne is not an endeavor, and we would not normally say "succeeds in the throne" (although it would probably be understood as meaning that he is a successful ruler).

Sentence #4 is not acceptable, we don't usually follow "succeed" by an infinitive.

Comment: One last thing, could you tell me the differences between **"I succeed in the game"** and **"I succeed to the game"** please?

Comment: The second is not acceptable at all. "succeed to" is can only be used like in sentence #3. Maybe you're confusing it with "proceed to", which refers to motion in the direction of something, like "proceed to the exit".